# How to get omniauth info from Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, google-oauth

When we configure Devise we put in config/initializers/devise.rb something like this:

```
  config.omniauth :google_oauth2, "[client_id].apps.googleusercontent.com", "[client_secret]"
```

I'm curious how to use this info (client_id and client_secret) inside the app?

For example,

```
flow = Google::APIClient::InstalledAppFlow.new(
  :client_id => client_secrets.client_id,
  :client_secret => client_secrets.client_secret,
  :scope => [YOUTUBE_READONLY_SCOPE]
)
```

I'd like to get this info from Devise instead of hardcoding it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add the `client_id` and `client_secret` in an `yml` file called `google.yml` (for example) and in `devise.rb` you could have something like:

```
config_google = YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root}/config/google.yml")
config.omniauth :google_oauth2, config_google["client_id"], config_google["client_secret"]
```

Same thing goes if you want to use the config outside the initializer. Just load the yml and use its contents.

Inside the yml you can have different keys for each environment (development, production, etc). Just make sure you load it properly.

```
YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root}/config/google.yml")[Rails.env] # for example
```

Comment: Well, that's not exactly what I was looking for, but looks really good. Thank you! I'll wait a little and accept it if nothing more devisable shows up.

Comment: @AlexanderGorg That's how I did it in the past and was enough .. What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: Do not misunderstand me - your solution looks even better than that I was looking for. However, I asked about retrieving this info from Devise. I'd like to give a little more time if somebody is already typing something that way